# SwiftUI TextField behaves weirdly when I bind its value (can't type Chinese, occasionally backspaces skip a character)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here's the code a minimal repro. I suspect its something to do with changing the SearchTerm causing the UI to rerender or something, but I can't quite figure this out. Ideally, I'd `onEditingChange` but I want to react to every individual `keypress`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchTerm: String = "Hello World!"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
            self.searchTerm
        }, set: {
            if $0 != self.searchTerm
            {
                self.searchTerm = $0
            }
        })
        
        return VStack{
            TextField("Search field", text: binding)
            Text(searchTerm)
        }
    }
}
```

[Here you can see a gif of the buggy behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTec6.gif)

(this is on the latest non-beta Xcode, Swift, macOS, etc.)

Edit: I think this might just be a SwiftUI bug - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128721

Comment: Why don't you use direct binding to `$searchTerm`?

Comment: This is just a minimal repro - my real scenario involves term -> (bla blah vlah vblah) -> searchresults in a list.

Oh! - and direct binding also still reproduces the bug

Comment: Oh turns out, the repro can be made even smaller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908880/swiftui-textfield-keyboard-flashes-and-breaks-typing-in-other-languages

Comment: I filled a bug in the apple bug reporting system for this. [Here](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4961227675533312) is the radar.

Answer (score 0):

[SwiftUI TextField keyboard flashes and breaks typing in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908880/swiftui-textfield-keyboard-flashes-and-breaks-typing-in-other-languages)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128721

Hi everyone else who also encounters this issue. I believe this is a platform bug that can't be worked around, and my solution was simply to use a wrapped UIKit UITextField... which is what I was hoping to avoid.